# sql injection attack on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Am building my own personal plugging for wordpress.

With code below, I can query and insert record to database via wordpress.  With code below, I know that am vulnerable to sql injection attack.

I know how to prevent injection via PDO and Mysqli but am concerned with wordpress. Does wordpress uses prepared statement.

Can someone show me how to prevent sql injection attack in wordpress with the code below.

```
global $wpdb;

// Add record
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $name = $_POST['txt_name'];
    $uname = $_POST['txt_uname'];
    $email = $_POST['txt_email'];
    $tablename = $wpdb->prefix."myplugin";

    if($name != '' && $uname != '' && $email != ''){
        $check_data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$tablename." WHERE username='".$uname."' ");
        if(count($check_data) == 0){
            $insert_sql = "INSERT INTO ".$tablename."(name,username,email) values('".$name."','".$uname."','".$email."') ";
            $wpdb->query($insert_sql);
            echo "Save sucessfully.";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress does support prepared statements (also known as parameterized queries), using [$wpdb->prepare()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/).

```
global $wpdb;

// Add record
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_POST['txt_name'];
    $uname = $_POST['txt_uname'];
    $email = $_POST['txt_email'];
    $tablename = $wpdb->prefix."myplugin";

    if($name != '' && $uname != '' && $email != ''){
        $check_data = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT * FROM {$tablename} WHERE username = %s ;"
            , [$uname]
        ));
        if(count($check_data) == 0){
            $insert_sql = $wpdb->prepare(
                "INSERT INTO {$tablename}(name,username,email) values(%s, %s, %s) ;"
                , [$name, $uname, $email]
            );
            $wpdb->query($insert_sql);
            echo "Save sucessfully.";
        }
    }
}
```

Two things to note:

- All parameters in this case were strings and therefore were replaced by `%s`, but you can also use `%d` for integers and `%f` for float, just as in [PHP sprintf()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sprintf.php).
- You do not need to add quotes around the string placeholders (`%s`). The `$wpdb->prepare()` method takes care of that.